# Retrieve NodePointer.properties that was not inserted into DB yet

Tags: python, neo4j, cypher, py2neo

I'm using py2neo to insert some data into my neo4j db.

I create arrays of NodePointers and Relations and insert them with

```
for i in rels:
    test_graph.create(i)
```

after the process.

During the creation of my arrays I would like to check if a specific NodePointer was already added to the array or not (don't want to create two NodePointers with same name).

Looking for a way to check a NodePointer properties, I've found this at py2neo documentation:

```
>>> alice.properties["name"]
'Alice'
```

but when I try to do:

```
def isThereAThisInHere(this, here):
    for i in here:
        if (i.properties["name"] == this):
            return i
    return False    

mVar = isThereAThisInHere(defWord.wordVar[0],tempVar)
if (mVar == False):
    mVar = Node("Variable",name=defWord.wordVar[0])
    tempVar.append(mVar)
```

I get: `'NodePointer' object has no attribute 'labels'`

Does anyone have a solution or suggestion for my problem? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the `(mVar == False)` comparison. Even though the error was raised at the `.properties["name"]` line.